# is there any difference in authorization between Magento.RestAPI 1.8 and 1.6

Tags: magento-1.8, api, rest-api

I'm using magento.restAPI and i'm very new to magento and i havent used any previous version of magento. 
Currently i'm having a magento rest Api 
i want to know whether its the same authentication process being used in magento 1.8 and 1.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the Magento changelog

[Release Notes - Magento 1.7.0.0 (Apr 24, 2012)](http://www.magentocommerce.com/download/release_notes#Release%20Notes%20-%20Magento%201.7.0.0%20%28Apr%2024,%202012%29)

You'll notice the `Major Highlights`, the 8th bullet isted is:

```
Added REST API
```

If you browse through all of the available changelogs, there is no further mention of REST modification in versions later than 1.7.0.0.

So yes, there is a difference in the REST API between versions 1.6 & 1.8 which is the existence of the API itself ;-)

Comment: No my point is is there any difference in Authentication or Authorization, like any new Properties or Fields has been added on to it

Comment: As I mentioned, there has been no further mention of REST modification after the implementation thereof. So no.